# c/c++ get handle control of an unnamed listbox

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am using this code to get the handle of a listbox I need but the problem is that I have 5 listboxes with same class name and no title

and it stops enumeration since it finds first listbox

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    hwlist = FindWindowEx(hwnd,0,"WTL_LISTVIEW", "");
    if(!hwlist)
        return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
}

int main(void)
{
    HWND a=FindWindow("Dialog", "");
    EnumChildWindows(a, &EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)"");
}
```

Comment: Give your child windows unique IDs when creating them, and find them with `GetDlgItem`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's the answer!

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is listbox from another application and it doesn't have unique id
sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: Then you'll need to find some other way to identify them - maybe by position within the parent window?

Comment: is there any possibility to resume enumeration until get all 5 listboxes ?

Comment: Don't return FALSE if you want the enumeration to continue. If you use the accessibility interfaces, the different list views may have different accessible names.